# python3. Reuse the same named arguments use to call the first function, to call a second function from within the first function

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, keyword-argument, named

Given the following function, and function call

```
def func1(cl, cmd, **kwargs):
    ...
    ...
    cl.conn()
    cl.func2(cmd, a="t1", b=20)
    resp = cl.proc_response()
    json_resp = json.loads(cl.format_resp(resp, 'json'))
    return json_resp

# call func1
cl = Client()
command = 'deblock'
deb = func1(cl, command , a="t1", b=20)
```

The objective is to be able to call cl.func2() from within func1 with the named arguments used to call func1.
but depending on the command, the number of named arguments can changed, there can be as many as 10, they are never the same arguments, nor the number of arguments. i.e.

```
bl = func1(client, 'block', c="t2", d=4, e=23, f="t7")
# then the call to func2 from within func1 will be:
cl.func2(cmd, c="t2", d=4, e=23, f="t7")
```

I have to do this func1 call at least 50 times, with different commands, so that if you look into func1, there are are least 5 lines of code, then 250 lines with similar code. Not very good

```
Note: I put kwargs, and tried many things but always unsuccessful.
I really hope this is possible to be done. 
The arguments of func2 have to be named, func2 does not accept dictionary.
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this, in python3.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which way was your attempt with `kwargs` unsuccessful? Could you show us that code? This should be exactly what this syntax is very helpful for, if I understand your goal correctly, so maybe you are pretty close already. :)

Comment: I tried, this to unpack kwargs

`params = [key+"="+str(value) for key, value in kwargs.items()]
#then
cl.func2(cmd, *params,sep=",")`
Combining, eval, exec, among other things. The issue seems to be related to the fact that a dynamic variable is being created, expression cannot contain assignment. I have spent quite sometime, but still don't see it. As a matter of fact not sure if it is possible. Very grateful for any help.

Comment: Did you try `cl.func2(cmd, **kwargs)` ? That would be the "standard" way of using it.

Comment: David, I thought I had tried that as well, but I just tried that now, and it worked. Don't know why I complicated this. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Great, happy you solved it :)